# how to get information about goal of action

Tags: ros2, rviz, moveit, microcontroller

I learned to generate trajectories while working with ros2_controller.

I want to take a closer look, find the goal in `/execute_trajectory/_action/`

I can only check the message type below.

`ros2 interface show moveit_msgs/action/ExecuteTrajectory`

I was able to understand the structure, but I don't know how it is used as an example.

I don't want anything custom. However, i want to use the existing message.

Because I need to know other messages, I wonder if the following is possible.

Is there a way to output /_action/goal as a topic?

Thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the hidden topic is the only way to see the action goal as a topic. But also, you shouldn't be looking at that. Its hidden for a reason so that you use the action client / server interfaces.

If you're just introspecting for debugging, then that's no problem to look at that topic once and again, but I just wouldn't rely on it as part of your application.